# Pickle and evaluation of sympy expressions

Tags: python, django, pickle, sympy

I have the problem that pickling/unpickling of sympy expressions may not return the inital expression, as in the following example

```
>>>with evaluate(False) : x = atan(sqrt(3))
>>>x
atan(sqrt(3))
>>> y = pickle.dumps(x)
>>> z = pickle.loads(y)
>>> z
pi/3
```

Is there a way to avoid the evaluation in the process?

The motivation is that I need to add sympy expressions to a request.session object in Django without them being altered in the process.

Comment: It sounds like unpickling in an `evaluate(False)` context might help. I haven't tried it, though, and I don't know if unpickling is supposed to behave this way by default.

Comment: Indeed it does work, thanks! In the django context, this means retrieving values from `request.session` in an `evaluate(False)` context.

Comment: That sounds like there might be thread-safety issues with different threads trying to enter and leave the `evaluate(False)` context in conflict with each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment by [user2357112](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112) answers the question.

```
>>>with evaluate(False) : x = atan(sqrt(3))
>>>x
atan(sqrt(3))
>>> y = pickle.dumps(x)
>>> with evaluate(False) : z = pickle.loads(y)
>>> z
atan(sqrt(3))
```